# How to know score of wi-fi channels?

Tags: java, android, wifi, frequency, analyzer

I trying to create Wifi analyzer app. And I need to get Rating of wifi channels. How can I do that ?

This is how I get wi-fi channels.

```
........
TextView tvChannel = (TextView) lv.getChildAt(wantedChild).findViewById(R.id.textViewChannel);
tvChannel.setText(" " + convertFrequencyToChannel(results.get(i).frequency));
.......

public static int convertFrequencyToChannel(int freq) {
    if (freq >= 2412 && freq <= 2484) {
        return (freq - 2412) / 5 + 1;
    } else if (freq >= 5170 && freq <= 5825) {
        return (freq - 5170) / 5 + 34;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is relevant. Anybody...